# Catching StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, exception, stream

I have some java code which calls a third party proprietary library:

```
public String decrypt(String inputString) {
    return ThirdPartyDecrypter.decrypt(inputString);
}
```

The above code compiles and works for 99% of users. However, if I intentionally submit a bad improper input string, the above method throws a java.io.StreamCorruptedException.

I would like to catch that exception and do something else with the error case:

```
public String decrypt(String inputString) {
    try {
        return ThirdPartyDecrypter.decrypt(inputString);
    } catch (StreamCorruptedExcepton streamException) {
        System.out.println("case streamException");
        streamException.printStackTrace(); // does not execute
            throw MyNewException(streamException);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("case e");
        e.printStackTrace(); 
            throw MyNewException(streamException);
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, the StreamCorruptedException is not caught and it is still thrown instead of MyNewException.

What do I need to do to catch the StreamCorruptedException? I've also read that StreamCorruptedException should be a checked exception. So how is the third party library throwing it (since they have not declared any throws in their API)?

Comment: The third-party code more than likely doesn't let the exception propagate and instead catches it internally, probably printing it. Can you show your full exception trace?

Comment: What's the third party software? Also, your code snippet won't compile as `streamException` will be out of scope in the second catch statement. The library might be throwing it's own `StreamCorrruptedException`, which might be why your catch statement isn't working.

Comment: @veer - If the third party library is catching it internally, why would my code die due to an exception? I'll try to post an update with my full stack trace.

Comment: @Dunes - The third party software isn't publicly available. Somebody wrote it and didn't leave the source code. I don't see what is wrong with my catch statement. Are you referring to the first or the second catch statement?

Comment: @Dunes - On second reading, you are correct that the catch (StreamCorruptedException) will not compile since the ThirdPartyDecrypter does not declare a throws. However, I don't know why the catch Exception e doesn't catch it.....

Comment: @David can you paste the exception? I suspect that the exception is wholly handled internally.

Comment: Your third party code is badly flawed if it requires a String to hold cipher text. Or is it base64-encoded as well?